# How to add libraries to Xamarin References lists

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin

Is there a place to put libraries(dlls) so they show up in the References list in a project to be selected. I know I can manually add them from my personal library, however I would like to be able to have them in the available list so all I need to do is select them. I assume there would be some way to indicate which platform they are for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under Edit References select .Net Assemblies and pick the dll to add to the project. When it is added the first time it will be in the references for future projects.

I went through and added my normal dlls even if not needed in the current project to get them in the reference list and then removed the extras from the that project. That way I have them available when needed.