# The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' missing error in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting this error:

> "MyApp\App.cs(7,7): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Xamarin'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?) (CS0246)".

I'm using Xamarin Studio to make a cross platform app via Xamarin.Forms. Whenever I build the basic form project I get this error and I don't know why.

I'm new in Xamarin.

Here is the code of app.cs:

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;             //This is the line where error occurs

namespace FIrstFormProject
{
    public class App
    {
        public static Page GetMainPage ()
        {
            return new ContentPage 
            {
                Content = new Label 
                {
                    Text = "Hello, Forms !",
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you referenced the dll which contains Xamarin.Forms in your project? (presumably something like Xamarin.Forms.dll)

Comment: @SamHolder no but i'm not getting option of adding that reference. can u tell me briefly ? may be this is reason of error

Answer (score 57):

MihaMarkic's post [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18323/the-type-or-namespace-page-could-not-be-found) led me to the right answer. For each project in your solution you'll need to do the following:

1. Select the project in the Solution tab
2. Select "Project" along the top menu
3. Select "Add Nuget Packages..."
4. Do a search for "Xamarin.forms"
5. Add "Xamarin.forms" to that project

This is the workflow that got it working on my Mac. I'm not sure what the exact steps are for you PC users out there.

Comment: works same way on PC - once I realized where to look for step 2 -- MENU "Project"; which has menu item "Add Nuget Packages..." for step 3.

Comment: for me, the "Add Nuget Packages.." doesn't work for me, so i clicked the "Update Nuget Packages..." it works fine.. thanks @eckyzero

Answer (score 9):

Do the following:

1. Go to Manage NuGet Packages for Solution
2. **Remove** Xamarin.Forms
3. **Reinstall** Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Maybe just updating can also help.

Comment: I will never understand why removing and reinstalling solves the problem, but it always does.

Answer (score 6):

I just had to add the Xarmin.Forms.Addin.dll in app's references. :) (Thanks @sam holder your hint in the comments led me to the answer.)

Comment: glad you got it fixed

Comment: Most of this answer is a thank you, rather than an actual answer. It would probably be better to lead with the solution, then credit the other user with leading you in the right direction. It also wouldn't hurt to flesh out the steps you took to solve the problem.

Comment: Tell us how you fixed it please. "Thanks" sucks.

Comment: This is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650220/how-to-add-libraries-to-xamarin-references-lists) to know how to add reference.And you just have to add Xamarin.Froms.Addin library to get through this error.

Comment: Where would "Xamarin.Forms.Addin" be located?

Comment: @ShilpaSoni Menu bar -> Project -> Add NuGet Packages -> Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 5):

I have to combine some previous answers:

- Reinstall Nugets (Xamarin.Forms)
- Restart VS2019

Comment: It did happen to me after updating `Xamarin.Forms` to v4.1 . I had to restart Visual Studio to get it working again.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to "Manage NuGet Packages...
2. View in Installed Tab
3. If Xamarine.Forms package exist, update it.
4. If not Go to Browse tab find Xamarine.Forms and install it.

Answer (score 2):

- Select Solution & Right click.
- Go to Manage Nuget packages for solution.
- Go to updates.
- if xamarin.forms is there, update it.

You are ready to work with xamarin.forms :)

Comment: After updating I needed to close and re-open VS (VS2017 in my case) before the references showed back up.

Comment: @AndyS. Thank you for your comment. It helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Select the solution & right click
Go to Restore Manage Nuget Packages

Answer (score 2):

After removing/reading Xamarin.Forms NuGet package two times and hot having this fixed, I had restarted my Visual Studio(15.9.0) and it worked. This was a brand new solution I created and started having this issue immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I had it today in the VS MAC.

Deleting the ".vs" hidden folder fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have VS 2019 and I was prompted to update the Android SDK. After doing this I got a load of compiler errors including `The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin'`
After updating my NuGet package to the latest version, the errors resolved (from 4.3.0.947036 to 4.3.0.991211)

Answer (score 1):

### Trivial solution to try before proceeding with more severe methods: **Restart Visual Studio**

---

The context in my case is that the solution was already compiling previously, yet stopped doing so after changes to the code. In my case all I did was change the XAML file, add a resource and reference said resource in the XAML file. Prior to this `Xamarin.Forms` was found, afterwards it was no longer found by Visual Studio for an unknown reason.

Restarting Visual Studio resolved the problem for me.

This is likely only relevant if `Xamarin.Forms` was found before and suddenly went missing, a restart is obviously unsuitable in fixing errors with the project setup.

This also sometimes (though not always) occurs when the `Xamarin.Forms` NuGet package is changed, *i.e.*  a different one is installed for projects.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

1. Install latest Microsoft .NET Portable Library Reference Assemblies.
2. Extract the file in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft .NET Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6\PortableReferenceAssemblies.zip" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable" in 64bit and  "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable" in 32 bit

3.Go to control panel select programs and features and right click xamarin choose repair.
4. Start xamarin studio again.

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I removed the `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` and `Xamarin.Forms` library in order to downgrade to an earlier version. I got it working again by resetting the Droid `packages.config` to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="22.1.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="1.4.2.6355" targetFramework="MonoAndroid44" />
</packages>
```

Then right-click the Droid `Packages` folder to *Restore* missing packages.
The final step is to add the `References` > `From Packages` to the **.Droid.csproj*

```
<Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.22.1.1\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.4.2.6355\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="FormsViewGroup">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.4.2.6355\lib\MonoAndroid10\FormsViewGroup.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Core">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.4.2.6355\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Xaml">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.4.2.6355\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Platform">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.4.2.6355\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for your Target. Some targets aren't compatible with Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall and reinstall Nuget Xamarin.Forms in both the Android and PCL library.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Visual Studio Installer and installed .Net classic apps package (sorry, i don't know exact name, because i have russian version)
And it helped me.

[image]