# The type or namespace name 'Page' could not be found in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm working on Xamarin Studio and beginner in it. I'm making cross platform app using Forms.  ut the basic project gives this error when i build it "Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Page' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" Please help me if someone know the answer.here is the code of app.cs:

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CrossPlatformAppForms
{
public class App
{
    public static Page GetMainPage ()    //This is the line where i'm getting the error
    {
        return new ContentPage { 
            Content = new Label {
                Text = "Hello, Forms !",
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            },
        };
    }
}
}
```

One more thing in MyApp.Android i'm getting a warning of incompatible target framework(.Net framework 4.5...)

Comment: As the error says, are you missing a reference to Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' missing in xamarin studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994273/the-type-or-namespace-name-xamarin-missing-in-xamarin-studio)

Comment: @Cheesebaron No buddy thats nt the solution i have checked this and notj=hing is missing. May be any .dll file is missing.

Comment: With reference the IDE means... "Did you forget to actually reference the assembly?!"

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994273/the-type-or-namespace-name-xamarin-missing-in-xamarin-studio

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix On that question error is on Xamarin.froms in this case error is on on that 'Page' function. I have added Xamarin.forms.dll and it did not solve this 'Page' namespace problem.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the other one, learn to read before posting please.

Answer (score -2):

Its not a duplicate of [The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' missing in xamarin studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994273/the-type-or-namespace-name-xamarin-missing-in-xamarin-studio) (the solution to solve the problem in the link is by adding Xarmin.Forms.Addin.dll in the reference), but I'am currently facing this problem in my Xamarin Studio as well, and I think its related to .NET 4.5 framework compatibility.

Comment: There is no answer here or solution to try, this would be more appropriate as a comment.