# Can't find SQLitePlatformIOS in Sqlite.net PCL

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've used nuget package manager to download [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/)

The example shows:

```
public class SQLiteFactoryiOS : ISQLiteFactory
{
    public SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection CreateConnection(string dbName)
    {
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), dbName);
        return new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformIOS(), path);
    }
}
```

The issue I am facing is that I can't reference SQLitePlatformIOS.
I even found it in the [source code](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/master/src/SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinIOS/SQLitePlatformIOS.cs), but I'm not able to reach the `.Platform` namespace, thus I'm unable to create a `SQLitePlatformIOS` object.

```
 using SQLite.Net; //.Platform.XamarinIOS <-- Compiler error if I try to reach this
```

The project I'm using to reference this is a portable class project, because in the references folder I see .NET Portable Subset.

The structure of the project is

iOS MainProject references Example Portable Project 
Example Portable Project references SQLite.Net-PCL

In the Portable Project I have

```
References
     .NET Portable Subset
     From Packages
          SQLite.Net
Packages
     SQLite.Net-PCL
Data
     Repositories
           ExampleRepository.cs
```

My example repository is

```
using System;
using Example.Data.DTO;
using Example.Models.Properties;

using SQLite.Net;

namespace Example.Data.Repositories
{
    public class ExampleRepository(string dbPath)
    {
        using (var db = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformIOS() /* Can't reference */, dbPath))
        {
             db.CreateTable<ExampleDTO>();
        }
    }
}
```

And I call this class from the iOS project.

```
partial void SaveObject(NSObject sender)
{
    var objectToSave = CreateObjectFromView();
    var dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Test.db3");
    var repo = new ExampleRepository(dbPath);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your project structure? If you're sharing code, there's no need to reference the iOS implementation in the PCL. The PCL needs only to be aware of the interface. The iOS project will inject the proper implementation

Comment: Ok give me a few minutes to edit my question

Comment: I just added the SQLite.Net-PCL reference to my iOS project and it is now able to reference the Platform namespace. Hmm...

Comment: Like I said, the PCL doesn't need to know about the iOS reference, it only needs to know the interface. Are you using any IoC/DI framework?

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to hide a namespace based on what project it is associated with.

Comment: That's the recommended way of dealing with cross platform code in a PCL. A commom interface is used by the PCL and the specific code that implements the interface is used in each specific app that uses the PCL. This way you can reuse the PCL in a elegant manner, without checking the current platform or using specific bits of hacky code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you're not finding the reference to the iOS implementation is because you don't have access to platform specific code in a PCL. In fact, you don't need it. All you need inside the PCL is the interface, the specific code will be injected using a DI framework, so the PCL uses the proper code for each platform without you having to check which platform you're using during runtime.

[Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/#PCL_Example) you can see an example on how dependency injection works (and it even uses SQLite)

Comment: That is the right answer. As for the DI, I'm looking for a better example of dependency injection in Xamarin iOS. While it is nice that the business layer is using constructor injection, I don't know how I feel about the Controllers referencing the static AppDelegate for the objects. I'm not sure Xamarin IoS can support the DI I am looking for. One that allows for pure constructor injection and object lifetime management with an IoC container.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the .Platform namespace has disappeared from the SQLite.Net PCL package.

The workaround is to download the source from https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL and then build the binaries yourself. To do this, open the solution in Xamarin Studio (as of typing this I'm on 5.10.3 Build 51), change the mode to Release (without targeting any specific hardware), and click `Build -> Build All`.

Then open your iOS project in Xamarin Studio, right-click on the References folder and select `Edit References...`, then click on the `.Net Assembly` tab, click `Browse...` and browse to the location of the SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinIOS.Unified.dll file which you've just built. It should be in `SQLite.Net-PCL-master/SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinIOS.Unified/bin/Release`

Although an old post from 2014, I found the SQLite.Net PCL GitHub link from https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28916/error-while-trying-to-install-sqlite-net-platform-xamarinios-2-4-1-please-help (See JuhaPehkonen's Dec 2014 post)

And a bit more info on adding references in Xamarin Studio can be found here: [How to add libraries to Xamarin References lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650220/how-to-add-libraries-to-xamarin-references-lists)